# Will the puzzle timer max out at 99 hours?

Tags: picross-s

In the Picross S series, puzzles have a timer in the top right formatted as hours, minutes, and seconds. What happens if you wait 99 hours to max out the timer? Will the timer stop counting?

[image: Picross timer]